# netctl: Static IP configuration lost automatically after few seconds of starting the interface

Tags: networking, arch-linux, dhcp, netctl, hyper-v

I am using netctl in Arch Linux on Hyper-V. I have two ethernet interfaces eth0 & eth1.

IP config:

1. eth0: dhcp (automatic configuration, no involvment of netctl)
2. eth1: static ip (10.10.10.1/8) using netctl profile
3. dhcpcd installed and enabled at startup
4. NetworkManager installed and enabled at startup

eth1 netctl profile (/etc/netctl/sth1static):

```
Description='Static IP config for eth1'
Interface=eth1
Connection=ethernet
IP=static
Address=('10.10.10.1/8')
Gateway='10.10.10.2'
DNS=('10.10.10.2')
```

To start the interface I am doing as follows:

```
netctl stop eth1static
ip link set eth1 down
netctl start eth1static
netctl enable eth1static
```

After following the above steps, I am able to see the static IP configuration applied to the interface using `ip a`. Also I am able to ping the guest interface from my host OS successfully. However after a minute or so, I see the interface lose its configuration and get a `fe80:` based IPv6 address only and the ping stops working... Even after reboot, I don't see the IP configurtion on the interface, where as the other interface (`eth0`) is working fine.

Could anyone suggest what's going wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: How do you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

As you use netctl profiles I assume that you also enabled netctl.service – so you end up with NetworkManager AND netctl. You should only use one of them and disable all others. What you see ist most probably interference from another network manager.